# How to use WriteBatch with Firebase storage?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase cloud database and firebase storage. I'm using the following code in order to remove two documents using `WriteBatch`:

```
WriteBatch batch = fireDB.batch();
batch.delete(docRef1);
batch.delete(docRef2);
batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        // code
    }
});
```

I want also to remove the image from the storage using `WriteBatch`, meaning, if one of them fails, they all fail to remove. I have a variable called `imageURL` which contains the URL of the image in the firebase storage. I tried:

```
batch.delete(storage.getStorage().getReferenceFromUrl(imageURL));
```

But it does not work because:

> 'delete(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)' in 'com.google.firebase.firestore.WriteBatch' cannot be applied to '(com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference)'

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run a single operation across multiple Firebase products.

The best you can do is:

- Perform the deletes in the order that leads to the least problems for your use-case. Typically this means deleting the images last, as having an orphaned image is less disruptive for an app than having a dangling reference to a non-existing image.
- Write robust code for the reading, that can deal with both orphaned images, and dangling references.
- Perform periodic cleanup, typically in a Cloud Function, getting rid of both orphaned files and dangling references.

Comment: How could these functions be to handle these cleanups? Would they be cloud functions that are executed once a day, for example? Could you refer me to an example, or some resource with an example of a cleanup function?